# Running a Complex MySQL QUERY using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tried to fetch the data from a table named 'gainfinal' using a complex query given below :

```
    SELECT  g.countrycode,
        sum(case when `year` = '1995' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1995",
        sum(case when `year` = '1996' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1996",
        sum(case when `year` = '1997' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1997",
        sum(case when `year` = '1998' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1998", 
        sum(case when `year` = '1999' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1999",
        sum(case when `year` = '2000' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2000",
        sum(case when `year` = '2001' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2001",
        sum(case when `year` = '2002' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2002",
         sum(case when `year` = '2003' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2003", 
         sum(case when `year` = '2004' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2004", 
         sum(case when `year` = '2005' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2005",
        sum(case when `year` = '2006' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2006",
        sum(case when `year` = '2007' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2007",
        sum(case when `year` = '2008' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2008",
        sum(case when `year` = '2009' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2009", 
         sum(case when `year` = '2010' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2010", 
         sum(case when `year` = '2011' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2011",
        sum(case when `year` = '2012' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2012"


FROM    `gainfinal` g
WHERE   `year` between '1995' and '2012'
GROUP BY `countrycode`
```

I am sure the Query has been running well because it returned right data while running in Xampp.

My PHP code is like this :

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = "";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database="climate";
     //$country = 'NPL';
    // $indices = 'foodfinal';
   // $country=$_GET["country"];

    // $indices=$_GET["indices"];


    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    $myquery = "SELECT  g.countrycode,sum(case when `year` = '1995' then `g.values` else 0 end) AS "1995",
        sum(case when `year` = '1996' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1996",
        sum(case when `year` = '1997' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1997",
        sum(case when `year` = '1998' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1998", 
        sum(case when `year` = '1999' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1999",
        sum(case when `year` = '2000' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2000",
        sum(case when `year` = '2001' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2001",
        sum(case when `year` = '2002' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2002",
         sum(case when `year` = '2003' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2003", 

         sum(case when `year` = '2004' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2004", 
         sum(case when `year` = '2005' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2005",
        sum(case when `year` = '2006' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2006",
        sum(case when `year` = '2007' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2007",
        sum(case when `year` = '2008' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2008",
        sum(case when `year` = '2009' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2009", 
         sum(case when `year` = '2010' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2010", 
         sum(case when `year` = '2011' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2011",
        sum(case when `year` = '2012' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2012"


FROM    `gainfinal` g
WHERE   `year` between '1995' and '2012'
GROUP BY `countrycode`";
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);

    if ( ! $query ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);  
     mysql_close($server);
      //header('Location: linegraph.html');
     // include( "linegraph.html");

?>
```

This PHP file had been returning right data for other queries. It only didn't work for this query onl. While running the PHP file, it says 
: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in C:\xampp\htdocs\climateapp\data\chloroplath\data.php on line 17. How can I run the Query using PHP.

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot use MySQL GROUP function instead of all your sum?

Comment: I am a bit horrified by your query. Isn't it possible for you to get the years as rows instead of columns?

Comment: @ Francesco, I need to get the years as columns.

Comment: @Civaist: may I ask you why? I think the reason of why you need the years as columns is an important detail that should be incorporated in the question.

Comment: @ Francesco. Sure !! It's actually for the visualization in a chloroplath map using D3. I need the data in that format so that yearwise plot can be made.

Comment: @Civaist: I am sure you can do some processing of the data in PHP or JavaScript, right?

Comment: It's ridiculous to do this in MySQL when you have PHP available for formatting.

Comment: But it would be better if I executed this Query. Are there any other options available( I mean, with processing of data in PHP or JavaScript? )

Comment: @ StrawBerry, how can I done the same using PHP. I need to obtain all the values of all unique years in a seperate column.

Comment: @Civaist: yes, you can begin by studying this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php create a new array, and use as keys the years, that are contained in the rows of the result from the query. Why is it so hard? This is not about PHP, but basic programming skills.

Comment: @civaist There are thousands of examples out there of how to take an ordered mysql result and display in an html table.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you could group by country code *and* year, you should be able to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT  
  g.countrycode,
  g.year,
  SUM(g.values) as summed
FROM    `gainfinal` g
WHERE   g.year between '1995' and '2012'
GROUP BY g.countrycode, g.year
```

Moreover, are you planning to add every year to your query? Seems like a lot of work to me.

Comment: I think there should be a comma after `g.year`

Comment: Thank you @Ende Neu. But, the above query doesn't return the values for all the years in seperate columns.

Comment: @Civaist Is there any particular reason why you want to have all the years on the column? If you want to achieve that than probably Gordon Linoff's answer can fix the error you are having but I would argue that for complexity and readability your query is not a good one, also you could process your sql results in php more easily than having to maintain this piece of code.

Comment: @Civaist With Ende Neu's approach the values would be rows instead of columns, and you can simply retrieve them with a loop, more efficiently than explicitly referencing individual columns like you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think your quotes are off.  The double quotes that surround:

```
     sum(case when `year` = '2003' then g.values else 0 end) AS "2003",
```

Are affecting the php code.  The easiest solution is to replace them with backticks:

```
     sum(case when `year` = '2003' then g.values else 0 end) AS `2003`,
```

Or, use names that don't need to be quotes:

```
     sum(case when `year` = '2003' then g.values else 0 end) AS value_2003,
```

EDIT:

You also have a problem in the first line.  This line:

```
SELECT  g.countrycode, sum(case when `year` = '1995' then `g.values` else 0 end) AS "1995",
```

should be:

```
SELECT g.countrycode, sum(case when `year` = '1995' then g.`values` else 0 end) AS `1995`,
```

Comment: Given the ready availability of application level code, this is in my opinion a poor way to solve this problem. So I've chosen to downvote this solution, in support of that opinion.

Comment: +1. Gordon has provided the correct answer. It's a PHP string literal problem.  (I'd opt use bacticks to enclose the identifiers, rather than double quotes. But with appropriate SQL_MODE enabled, MySQL will allow for ANSI style double quotes around identifiers, but those would **certainly** need to be properly **escaped** within a PHP string literal.

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . This isn't a question of MySQL.  It is a question of php.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I haven't the faintest idea what you are trying to say in your comment.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff, I replaced the double quotes with backticks. But now, it says : Unknown column 'g.values' in 'field list'

Comment: @Civaist . . . At least that is a MySQL error.  It is probably caused by your having "g.values" surrounded by backticks, rather than just "values".

Comment: @ Gordon. Thank you for your answer. Finally, It worked for me. @ Spencer7593I didn't wrap g.values in the backticks and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using double quotes in your query, which is terminating the string prematurely. Consider using a [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) instead:

```
<?php
$myquery = <<<'END_OF_QUERY'
SELECT  g.countrycode,sum(case when `year` = '1995' then `g.values` else 0 end) AS "1995",
        sum(case when `year` = '1996' then g.values else 0 end) AS "1996",
        // rest of query
END_OF_QUERY;
```

Nowdocs are a convenient way of defining multiline "raw" strings, such as a query, when you don't want the contents to be parsed. This allows you to use whatever quotes you want within the query.